# Jquery load an external img src into the pages img src

Tags: jquery, load

I have an image on a page with an already existing src on an image, but I want to replace it by loading an external pages img src and replace it with the new one. Below is my code but it's not working. Please can you see the error?

```
<script>
                $(document).ready(function()
                {




    $dataImportURL = "/tv.aspx";
                    $(".videoThumbContainer img.attr('src')").load($dataImportURL + " #mediaImageContainer img.videoThumbImage.attr('src')");
                });
                </script>
                <div class="videoThumbContainer"><a class="videoPath" href="http://mydeo.vo.llnwd.net/o1/u/m3/b71658af521441fbb2dfbe71399ef1a1.mp4"><span class="videoThumbPlayBtn"></span><img class="videoThumbImage" src="/Assets/Manchester Arndale/3b37d9cf-3819-4b41-8efd-8464f513046e.jpg" /></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Start here:

```
$dataImportURL = "http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120925054351/victorious/images/a/aa/Puppy1.jpg";

$(".videoThumbContainer img").attr('src', $dataImportURL)
```